# ImportError: cannot import name 'stacked_violin' from 'scanpy.plotting._anndata'?

Tags: python, scanpy

Until a couple of days ago, my code using the scanpy library worked fine, but last night it broke and threw me a new error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./scanpy_normalization.py", line 4, in <module>
    import scanpy.api as sc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scanpy/api/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from . import pl
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scanpy/api/pl.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ..plotting._anndata import scatter, violin, ranking, clustermap, stacked_violin, heatmap, dotplot, matrixplot, tracksplot
ImportError: cannot import name 'stacked_violin' from 'scanpy.plotting._anndata' (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scanpy/plotting/_anndata.py
```

I import scanpy as

```
import scanpy.api as sc
```

and I update to the latest version of scanpy (if any) everytime I run the code. Was there a change in the last couple of days that I missed? Help is appreciated!

Comment: That is why relying on underscore names is risky :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely a bug in the module and seems like its stemming from the latest version that you must have upgraded to.

The error as it states

> cannot import name 'stacked_violin' from 'scanpy.plotting._anndata'

and this is true since this [_anndata.py](https://github.com/theislab/scanpy/blob/master/scanpy/plotting/_anndata.py) it refers to does not contains that method. It is in fact in another file called [stack_violin.py](https://github.com/theislab/scanpy/blob/master/scanpy/plotting/_anndata.py). See [here](https://github.com/theislab/scanpy/blob/43379e038c5db3f917f45cc69889de0dcb6caa35/scanpy/plotting/_stacked_violin.py#L544) for that function.

To fix it you can simply take the hard way of overwriting the library so that the method is present in the file `_anndata.py` or you can simply revert back to the earlier version. There's also no need to update the library frequently unless there is a real need, and such error is often expected when elevating versions.

Comment: It's also great that you have taken the initiative to create an issue on Github. Feel free to update here once you get a solution there.

Comment: Yeah I looked closer at the new codebase and found the error, hopefully they update it soon. In the meanwhile, I reverted back to a previous version, thanks for your help!